# Julia Command Line Running Processes in Parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, julia

I have a Julia script that converts csvs to a binary format. Trust me it's great. I also have many (seemingly innumerable) csvs that I want to process. It's a shared network and so I can only process five files at a clip without savagely burdening the CPU and making my coworkers irate and potentially unstable. Accordingly, I want to run the script in groups of five, wait for them to finish, and then run the next batch as background processes until it's Miller time all using Julia's wonderful run() function ala:

```
      julia csvparse3.jl /home/file1.csv > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I'm fairly certain that I could sidestep all of this by using addprocs() and pmap() if I made my parsing script into a Julia module/function. However, the reason I'm asking this is because I don't know what I would then do if my original script was written in Fortran or even worse Python? Is there a way for me to achieve my aforementioned goals for an arbitrary number of external programs, ascertain when the processes are finished, and start anew in the context of a simple loop? Many thanks.

Comment: [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: Besides `parallel`, you can also use `xargs -P`, e.g.,
`seq -f "echo %.0f; sleep 1" 100 | xargs -P 8 -n 1 -d "\n" sh -c`.

Comment: Do you actually want to _"run the script in groups of five"_ or have a maximum of five executing at the same time?

Comment: In groups of five, but on the last iteration probably would be less than five.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Parallel you can run:

```
parallel -j5 julia csvparse3.jl ::: /home/*.csv > /dev/null 2>&1
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: Complete and thoughtful answer. Much appreciated. I'm still curious to know if there is a more Julia way. Skoal.

Comment: @ChaseCB is 'Skoal' the same as 'skål'?

Comment: yes no swedish keyboard intelligence (or intelligence of any sort for that matter) over here.